# UnboundLocalError in python while returning list variable

Tags: python, list

I am creating a python script to load data from a csv file. I want that data to be used for training of neural network and so I want its format to be a list of tupples (x,y) where x and y are numpy array containing input and output. But when I return that list(td in following code) I get this error 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'td' referenced before assignment'

**Moderators**, there are many questions about this error on stackoverflow and I have read them and still couldn't find a solutions so I am posting this.

```
import csv
import numpy as np


def load_data():
    // loading the file
    with open('train.csv','rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
        // these if statements are to check if any of the field in csv file
        // is empty or not
            if(row['start_date'] != ""): 
                a = True
            if(row['sold'] != ""):
                b = True
            if(row['euribor_rate'] != ""):
                c = True
            if(row['libor_rate'] != ""):
                d = True
            if(row['bought'] != ""):
                e = True
            if(row['creation_date'] != ""):
                f = True
            if(row['sell_date'] != ""):
                g = True
            if(row['return'] != ""):
                h = True
            if(a and b and c and d and e and f and g and h):
            // if any of the fields is empty then go to next row 
                pass
            else:
            // now grab the fields 
                mrow = {'sd':row['start_date'],'s':row['sold'],'er':row['euribor_rate'],'lr':row['libor_rate'],'b':row['bought'],'cd':row['creation_date'],'sd':row['sell_date'],'r':row['return']}
                // this will change the data type of fields to float
                int_dict = dict((k,float(v)) for k,v in mrow.iteritems())
                // save an input data field in x
                x = np.array([int_dict['s']])
                // save the output data field in y
                y = np.array([int_dict['r']])
                // put them in tuple
                tuple = (x,y)
                //make a list
                td = []
                // append them to list
                td.append(tuple)
    //return the list
    return td
```

As most of the answers say - that is - to declare td = [] outside of function and then using 'global td' and then td.append() . That also didn't worked. It then didn't gave the error but it returned a empty list.

Comment: Does your code ever go into `else` part?

Comment: oh...i was mssing the basic thing

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not entering in the `else` part of the loop. To avoid that, you'll probably need to move the `td` part to the top of the loop, so it's always defined:

```
def load_data():
    with open('train.csv','rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
        td = []
        for row in reader:
            ...
```